# php code appending a NULL to result

Tags: php, rest, http-post, return-value

I am adding token-based authentication to my rest service.

I this added a `php` function in a static class that is defined as follows:

```
// file jwt.php
class JWT {
    static function get_token($username, $password) {
        // .... do a lot of things
        $token = "xxx=.yyy.zzz=";
        echo "test before return: " . $token . " __end\r\n";
        return $token;
    }
}
```

The method is called from a main class as follows :

```
require_once 'jwt.php';
class myRestAPI extends API {
    protected function login() {
        if ($this->method == 'POST') {
            echo "Entering method...\r\n";
            $token = JWT::get_token($this->request['usr'], $this->request['pwd']);
            echo "got token..." . $token . " __end\r\n";
            if (isset($token)) {
                return json_encode($token);
            }
        }
        return null;
     }
}
```

Now, for some reason I cannot understand, there is a "NULL" output coming in between the end of `JWT::get_token` and the first `echo` after the function:

```
Entering method...
test before return: xxx=.yyy.zzz=__end
NULL
got token...xxx=.yyy.zzz=__end
```

I have no damn clue as to where this comes from... And more annoyingly, this spoils my entire APIs result, which always return `null`...

Any idea as to where this could possibly come from?

Comment: Where is `$token` being set a value in jwt.php?

Comment: @NoaLea just prior the `echo`... I've amended (the `$token` variable prints perfectly as expected when echoing it!)

Comment: `echo "got token..." . $token " __end\r\n";` You have an error here. You forgot a `.` after `$token`. Maybe that should fix it?

Comment: @NoaLea oh sorry - copy-paste error... Corrected in question! But doesn't change any of the issue though!